# Google cloud batch dataflow issue

Tags: google-app-engine, serverless, dataflow, serverless-architecture

when I am going to read data from a bigquery table and write it in to the another bigquery table  using batch dataflow using apache beam and java.

A temp dataset  created in to the same project however temptable expired after 1 day but temp dataset still part of the Biquery .

I am using batch dataflow using template creation in google cloud.

if anyone face this kind of issue please reply .

Answer (score 0):

That is because [expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time) could be set only in tables not in datasets, you can get the [information about your temp dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-metadata#getting_dataset_information) using the commands :

```
bq ls -a
bq show --format=prettyjson $TEMP_DATASET
```

There you will find the "defaultPartitionExpirationMs" and "defaultTableExpirationMs" but anything related to "expiration dataset".